# Help with MCP23S08

Tags: arduino, spi

I’m not sure how to connect an [MCP23S08](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP23008-MCP23S08-Data-Sheet-DS20001919.pdf) IO expander or write Arduino code for it.

I would like the IO expanders to report button presses but I’m not sure where to start. It was recommended to create a byte buffer and transfer the data through each expander but I’m unsure of how that’s supposed to work.

I’m using one CS line for all the expanders which is a daisy-chained method. I can’t even get the system to blink with simple coding.

My other problem is that it’s a motherboard so the design can’t be changed at this time. I tried asking on the Arduino forums but I don’t think anyone there has the knowledge or experience with this method. I also think I’m getting my addresses wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Also this is using SPI as the form of communication.

[image]

Comment: From a quick view of the data sheet the 23S08 chip address is 7 bits with the top 3 set to 010 (2), and the bottom set to 0,0,A1,A0. So your address options are only 20, 21, 22, 23.  Be sure you have the chip number correct, the similar MCP23008 has 3 selectable address pins while the MCP23S08 only has 2.

Comment: Are you sure that these can be daisy-chained? Not all SPI parts can.

Comment: I just read on the data sheet that the address pin allows for the use of a single cs line

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you cannot daisy chain them, chapter 1.3.3.3 in the datasheet explains it. You always have sequences containing an operation code byte, an address byte and one or more data bytes within one CS low period. If you send such a sequence to the first chip, the next one in chain will interpret the output of the first chip as *something* not intended or useful.